# Swift modify node rotation based on globe coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, vector, scenekit

I have a 3d globe built with swift and SceneKit and to represent the users current location I use a torus (donut shaped object). The users location can be anywhere in the world and simply adding the node to the globe does not make it flush (aligned with globe). I have to modify the nodes eulerAngles in order to make it flat with the earth. My function doesn't work to properly align the shape with the earth given any unique location. I want the function to position the torus flush based on any set of latitude and longitude.

```
    let dotNode = SCNNode(geometry: lowerCircle)
 
    dotNode.eulerAngles = getRotation(lat: viewModel.currentLocation?.lat ?? 0.0, long: viewModel.currentLocation?.long ?? 0.0)

    func getRotation(lat: Double, long: Double) -> SCNVector3 {
        let latRad = lat * .pi / 180.0
        let lonRad = long * .pi / 180.0

        let rotationX = Float(-latRad)
        let rotationY = Float(lonRad)
        let rotationZ = Float(lonRad)

        return SCNVector3Make(rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ)
        
        //example
        //slightly correct rotation for Saudi Arabia
        //SCNVector3Make(.pi / 3.75, 0, -.pi / 4)
    }
```

Comment: do you have more details, about how your scene setup looks like? is the torus node a child of the earth node or is it directly added to the root node? you could probably calculate the vector from the torus node to the center of the earth and find the proper angle with a cross-product.

Comment: @ZAY the torus is the child of the earth node. Could you demonstrate how to use a cross-product.

Comment: I think someone already answered it ;) but yeah, this is the deluxe version of what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [**torus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry), in the context of 3D graphics or modeling (like in the SceneKit framework used in Swift, with [`SCNTorus`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntorus)), is a geometric shape resembling a donut or a ring.

[image: Torus]

In your case, the torus is being used to represent a specific location on the globe, likely a user's current location.

Since the globe is a sphere, simply placing the torus at a point based on latitude and longitude is not enough. The torus also needs to be oriented so that it sits flush against the globe's surface. That requires adjusting its rotation to align properly with the curvature of the Earth at that specific point.

> The torus is the child of the earth node.

The torus being a child of the earth node, any rotation or positioning applied to the torus is relative to the earth node. That simplifies the process of aligning the torus with the globe's surface at a specific geographical location. Instead of considering the entire scene's coordinate system, you only need to adjust the torus in relation to the earth node.

That would be:

```swift
func getTorusOrientation(lat: Double, long: Double) -> SCNVector4 {
    let latRad = lat * .pi / 180.0
    let lonRad = long * .pi / 180.0

    // Calculate position vector
    let x = cos(latRad) * cos(lonRad)
    let y = cos(latRad) * sin(lonRad)
    let z = sin(latRad)

    let positionVector = SCNVector3(x, y, z)

    // Updated up vector (assuming Y-axis is 'up' in the coordinate system)
    let upVector = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0)

    // Calculate cross-product
    let crossProduct = positionVector.cross(upVector)

    // Calculate angle for rotation
    let angle = acos(positionVector.dot(upVector))

    return SCNVector4(crossProduct.x, crossProduct.y, crossProduct.z, angle)
}

extension SCNVector3 {
    func cross(_ vector: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 {
        return SCNVector3(
            self.y * vector.z - self.z * vector.y,
            self.z * vector.x - self.x * vector.z,
            self.x * vector.y - self.y * vector.x
        )
    }

    func dot(_ vector: SCNVector3) -> Float {
        return (self.x * vector.x + self.y * vector.y + self.z * vector.z)
    }
}

// Usage
dotNode.orientation = getTorusOrientation(lat: viewModel.currentLocation?.lat ?? 0.0, 
                                          long: viewModel.currentLocation?.long ?? 0.0)
```

The `positionVector` is calculated using the latitude (`lat`) and longitude (`long`) values. That vector points from the center of the earth (assumed to be the origin in this coordinate system) to the location on the globe's surface where the torus should be placed.

The `upVector` is set to `(0, 1, 0)`, a standard way to define the 'up' direction in many 3D coordinate systems.

The `crossProduct` of the `positionVector` and the `upVector` is computed: it gives the axis around which we need to rotate the torus. That axis is perpendicular to both the position vector and the initial up vector of the torus, which is exactly what is needed for the correct orientation.

The `angle` for the rotation is calculated using the dot product between the `positionVector` and the `upVector`. That angle is the amount by which the torus needs to rotate around the `crossProduct` axis to align correctly with the globe's surface at the specified geographical location.

The [`SCNVector4`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnvector4) created from the `crossProduct` axis and the `angle` is then used to set the orientation of the torus. That makes sure the torus is not just positioned at the correct latitude and longitude, but also oriented properly so that it appears flush with the globe's surface.

---

Note that an `SCNTorus` from SceneKit can reuse the `getTorusOrientation()` defined above.

```swift
// Create a torus
let torus = SCNTorus(ringRadius: 1.0, pipeRadius: 0.1)
let torusNode = SCNNode(geometry: torus)

// Set the torus orientation (using the previously discussed getTorusOrientation function)
torusNode.orientation = getTorusOrientation(lat: viewModel.currentLocation?.lat ?? 0.0, 
                                            long: viewModel.currentLocation?.long ?? 0.0)

// Add the torus node to the earth node
earthNode.addChildNode(torusNode)
```

You would create an `SCNTorus` object with specific radius values, and then wrap it in an `SCNNode` (which is `torusNode`). The orientation of this node is set using the `getTorusOrientation` function, aligning it correctly on the globe. Finally, the torus node is added as a child to the earth node, maintaining the hierarchical relationship necessary for correct positioning and orientation.

---

> Maybe I can just modify the eulerAngles to apply the correct rotation. Would you know how to make that work if it's a viable approach?

Modifying Euler angles directly can be a viable approach, but trickier because of issues like [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock). See for instance "[Understanding Gimbal Lock and how to prevent it](https://base.movella.com/s/article/Understanding-Gimbal-Lock-and-how-to-prevent-it?language=en_US)".
It can be more intuitive in some cases, especially when dealing with geographic coordinates. But it may not handle all rotation scenarios as well as [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).

The key is to rotate the torus node first for latitude (around the X-axis) and then for longitude (around the Y-axis):

```swift
func getEulerAngles(lat: Double, long: Double) -> SCNVector3 {
    // Convert lat and long to radians
    let latRad = lat * .pi / 180.0
    let longRad = long * .pi / 180.0

    // For latitude: Rotate around the X-axis
    let rotationX = -latRad // Negative because SceneKit uses a right-handed coordinate system

    // For longitude: Rotate around the Y-axis
    let rotationY = longRad

    // No rotation around the Z-axis
    let rotationZ = 0.0

    return SCNVector3(rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ)
}

// Usage
dotNode.eulerAngles = getEulerAngles(lat: viewModel.currentLocation?.lat ?? 0.0, 
                                     long: viewModel.currentLocation?.long ?? 0.0)
```

Make sure that your globe is oriented correctly in SceneKit. The Earth's north pole should be aligned along the positive Y-axis in this setup. That should orient the torus correctly according to the given latitude and longitude.

---

> Your solution using the Euler angles is basically correct.
> If you add a minus 1.57 rads like `let rotationX = -latRad - 1.57` then the solution works perfectly, and the torus is flush anywhere on the globe. I am not sure why you have to subtract 90 degrees, but it works.

The need to subtract 1.57 radians (which is approximately 90 degrees) from the rotation around the X-axis can be explained by understanding the initial orientation of the torus and how it needs to be positioned relative to the globe's surface.

The torus, by default, might be oriented such that its 'hole' faces upwards along the Y-axis. That is a common default orientation for objects like rings or toruses in 3D modeling.

When you set the rotation for the latitude (`rotationX`), you are essentially tilting the torus forward or backward to match the latitude. However, if the torus's hole is initially facing upwards, you need an additional 90 degrees (or π/2 radians) rotation to make the torus lie in the plane of the latitude circle.

Subtracting 1.57 (or π/2) radians rotates the torus so that it aligns correctly with the latitude lines on the globe. Without this adjustment, the torus would stand upright at the equator instead of lying flat along the globe's surface.

The updated function would be:

```swift
func getEulerAngles(lat: Double, long: Double) -> SCNVector3 {
    let latRad = lat * .pi / 180.0
    let longRad = long * .pi / 180.0

    let rotationX = -latRad - 1.57 // Adjust for the initial orientation of the torus
    let rotationY = longRad
    let rotationZ = 0.0

    return SCNVector3(rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ)
}

// Usage
dotNode.eulerAngles = getEulerAngles(lat: viewModel.currentLocation?.lat ?? 0.0, 
                                     long: viewModel.currentLocation?.long ?? 0.0)
```

Comment: Thanks! The orientation isn't quite correct. I tried it with different points on the globe and it either scales the torus in a weird way or isn't aligned correctly.

Comment: @ahmed maybe the up vector isn't correct? `let upVector = SCNVector3(0, 0, 1)` instead of `let upVector = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0)`?

Comment: I tried a few different upVector configurations and it didn't fix it. The orientation attribute shouldn't change the scale of the torus but Ive noticed changing the up vector changes the scale of the torus. Having a upVector of SCNVector3(0, 0, 0) is the only configuration that isn't changing its scale but when doing so the torus points straight up regardless of its globe position

Comment: @ahmed Is the resulting quaternion (axis-angle representation) normalized? A non-normalized quaternion can result in unexpected scaling.

Comment: I tried normalizing both the up vector and cross product and it didn't really do anything to solve the issue. Maybe I can just modify the eulerAngles to apply the correct rotation. Would you know how to make that work if it's a viable approach.

Comment: @ahmed Sure, I have edited the answer to illustrate that approach.

Comment: Thanks von your solution using the Euler angles is basically correct. If you add a minus 1.57 rads like **let rotationX = -latRad - 1.57** then the solution works perfectly and the torus is flush anywhere on the globe. Not sure why you have to subtract 90 degrees but it works.

Comment: @ahmed Great, well done! I have edited the answer to include your conclusion, as well as a possible explanation.

Comment: Maybe you can also help with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77790467/swift-double-tap-and-single-tap-gestures-both-register?noredirect=1#comment137137763_77790467

Comment: Von can you look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77836428/swift-ui-changing-view-position-with-drag-raises-ui-bug