# SwiftUI changing view position with drag raises UI bug

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a graph in SwiftUI that represents a stock assets price. The user can drag on the graph which presents an overlay line view that moves along with the drag gesture. The purpose of this overlay view is to pinpoint the specific point of the graph that the user is analyzing.

When the user drags on the graph everything works just fine and the view appears but the overlay line view is glitchy and doesn't move smoothly with the drag. The only thing that is animated is showing the overlay and hiding it, and this only is done at the start and end of a gesture so I'm not sure why I get this buggy UI.

If I drag the line around for a few seconds the following warning appears in the console:

> Invalid sample AnimatablePair<AnimatablePair<CGFloat, CGFloat>, AnimatablePair<CGFloat, CGFloat>>(first: SwiftUI.AnimatablePair<CoreGraphics.CGFloat, CoreGraphics.CGFloat>(first: 11.0, second: 0.0), second: SwiftUI.AnimatablePair<CoreGraphics.CGFloat, CoreGraphics.CGFloat>(first: 0.0, second: 0.0)) with time Time(seconds: 0.0) > last time Time(seconds: 0.01664249994792044)`

Code:

```
 GraphView(coin: data).frame(height: 300)
        .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ value in
            if abs(value.translation.width) > abs(value.translation.height) {
                withAnimation { showPlot = true }
                barTranslation = value.location.x
            }
        }).onEnded({ value in
            withAnimation { showPlot = false }
        }).updating($isDrag, body: { value, out, _ in
            out = true
        }))
        .onChange(of: isDrag) { _ in
            if !isDrag {
                showPlot = false
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
            VStack(spacing: 0){
                Text(currentPlot)
                    .font(.caption.bold())
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    .padding(.bottom, 35)
                    .position(x: barTranslation)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.gray)
                    .frame(width: 1, height: 300)
                    .position(x: barTranslation)
                Spacer()
            }
            .opacity(showPlot ? 1 : 0)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [`withAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/withanimation(_:_:)/) inside the `DragGesture().onChanged`, try and update the position of the overlay directly. That should give you a smoother drag experience.
And keep the animations for showing and hiding the overlay in the `.onEnded` part of the gesture.

```swift
GraphView(coin: data).frame(height: 300)
    .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ value in
        if abs(value.translation.width) > abs(value.translation.height) {
            showPlot = true
            barTranslation = value.location.x
        }
    }).onEnded({ value in
        withAnimation { showPlot = false }
    }).updating($isDrag, body: { value, out, _ in
        out = true
    }))
    .onChange(of: isDrag) { _ in
        if !isDrag {
            withAnimation { showPlot = false }
        }
    }
    .overlay(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            Text(currentPlot)
                .font(.caption.bold())
                .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                .padding(.bottom, 35)
                .position(x: barTranslation)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.gray)
                .frame(width: 1, height: 300)
                .position(x: barTranslation)
            Spacer()
        }
        .opacity(showPlot ? 1 : 0)
    }
```

Here, the position of the overlay view (`barTranslation`) is updated directly within the `DragGesture().onChanged` closure without wrapping it in `withAnimation`. That change makes sure the position of the overlay updates immediately as the drag gesture changes, which should provide a smoother experience.

```swift
.onChanged({ value in
    if abs(value.translation.width) > abs(value.translation.height) {
        showPlot = true
        barTranslation = value.location.x
    }
})
```

The animations are now only applied in the `.onEnded` part of the gesture. That makes sure the animations are used only for showing and hiding the overlay when the drag gesture starts and ends, rather than trying to animate the position changes during the drag.

```swift
.onEnded({ value in
    withAnimation { showPlot = false }
})
```

---

> The bug still occurs though even when removing the with animation. And the warning still prints out a lot.

Make sure the gesture state is managed correctly. Sometimes, improper handling of gesture states can lead to unexpected behaviors. You might want to explicitly manage the state of the drag gesture.
The placement of animation modifiers can have unforeseen effects. Try removing any global or implicit animations applied to the parent view that might be affecting the overlay's behavior.
Redundant or conflicting updates to state variables like `showPlot` and `barTranslation` can cause issues.

The warning message indicates an issue with animatable values. Debug these values to see if they are being updated in an unexpected manner. Perhaps the `position(x: barTranslation)` is receiving values that are not valid or expected.

Sometimes using [`.offset(x:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/offset(x:y:)) for moving views can provide smoother animations and updates compared to [`.position(x:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/position(x:y:)). The `.offset` modifier moves the view from its original position, which can be more efficient.

You could try and modify the `.overlay` part using `.offset`:

```swift
.overlay(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
    VStack(spacing: 0){
        Text(currentPlot)
            .font(.caption.bold())
            .foregroundStyle(.gray)
            .padding(.bottom, 35)
            .offset(x: barTranslation - initialPosition)
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.gray)
            .frame(width: 1, height: 300)
            .offset(x: barTranslation - initialPosition)
        Spacer()
    }
    .opacity(showPlot ? 1 : 0)
}
```

`initialPosition` represents the initial position of the overlay view. That change makes sure `barTranslation` updates the view's position relative to its original position.

If these approaches still do not resolve the issue, it may be necessary to review the entire view hierarchy and how the gesture interacts with other parts of your SwiftUI view.

Comment: Thanks, the bug still occurs though even when removing the with animation. And the warning still prints out a lot.

Comment: Thanks can you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77857283/unable-to-present-image-above-all-windows-swift-ui

Comment: @ahmed You seem to have an answer already. I had a solution where  `TopImageView` remains a `ViewModifier`, and it is applied to a placeholder view (`Color.clear`) in `ContentView`. That would maintain the structure of `TopImageView` as a modifier and leverages SwiftUI's view modifier system to add custom behavior to an existing view.

Comment: Would you look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77934096/modify-swift-ui-view-without-using-ios-17-modifier