# Modify Swift UI view without using iOS 17 modifier

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios17

I have some code below that creates a custom navigation stack that enables full screen swipes to navigation away from the view. I want to support iOS 17 with this custom Navigation stack but some of the on change modifiers are only for iOS 17.

How can I modify `.onChange(of: isEnabled, initial: true) { oldValue, newValue in` which is inside of `fileprivate struct FullSwipeModifier: ViewModifier {` to work with iOS16 and have the same functionality? I tried using an `onReceive` modifier instead but I couldn't get that to work.

Additionally where would be the best spot to execute a function when a view is swiped away. I don't want the function to execute mid swipe but rather at the end of the swipe when the view has been popped from the navigation stack. I can definitely use a `onDisappear` but I'd rather not for my specific case.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isEnabled: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        FullSwipeNavigationStack {
             NavigationLink("Leading Swipe View") {
                 Text("hello").enableFullSwipePop(isEnabled)
             }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct FullSwipeNavigationStack<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content
    /// Full Swipe Custom Gesture
    @State private var customGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
        let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
        gesture.name = UUID().uuidString
        gesture.isEnabled = false
        return gesture
    }()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            content
                .background {
                    AttachGestureView(gesture: $customGesture)
                }
        }
        .environment(\.popGestureID, customGesture.name)
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .init(customGesture.name ?? "")), perform: { info in
            if let userInfo = info.userInfo, let status = userInfo["status"] as? Bool {
                customGesture.isEnabled = status
            }
        })
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func enableFullSwipePop(_ isEnabled: Bool) -> some View {
        self
            .modifier(FullSwipeModifier(isEnabled: isEnabled))
    }
}

/// Custom Environment Key for Passing Gesture ID to it's subviews
fileprivate struct PopNotificationID: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: String?
}

fileprivate extension EnvironmentValues {
    var popGestureID: String? {
        get {
            self[PopNotificationID.self]
        }
        
        set {
            self[PopNotificationID.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}

/// Helper View Modifier
fileprivate struct FullSwipeModifier: ViewModifier {
    var isEnabled: Bool
    /// Gesture ID
    @Environment(\.popGestureID) private var gestureID
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onChange(of: isEnabled, initial: true) { oldValue, newValue in
                guard let gestureID = gestureID else { return }
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init(gestureID), object: nil, userInfo: [
                    "status": newValue
                ])
            }
            .onDisappear(perform: {
                guard let gestureID = gestureID else { return }
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init(gestureID), object: nil, userInfo: [
                    "status": false
                ])
            })
    }
}

/// Helper Files
fileprivate struct AttachGestureView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return UIView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.02) {
            /// Finding Parent Controller
            if let parentViewController = uiView.parentViewController {
                if let navigationController = parentViewController.navigationController {
                    /// Checking if already the gesture has been added to the controller
                    if let _ = navigationController.view.gestureRecognizers?.first(where: { $0.name == gesture.name }) {
                        print("Already Attached")
                    } else {
                        navigationController.addFullSwipeGesture(gesture)
                        print("Attached")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension UINavigationController {
    /// Adding Custom FullSwipe Gesture
    /// Special thanks for this SO Answer
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714595/extend-default-interactivepopgesturerecognizer-beyond-screen-edge
    func addFullSwipeGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let gestureSelector = interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.value(forKey: "targets") else { return }
        
        gesture.setValue(gestureSelector, forKey: "targets")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
}

fileprivate extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        sequence(first: self) {
            $0.next
        }.first(where: { $0 is UIViewController}) as? UIViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried removing oldValue which is the pre-iOS 17 version ?

Comment: As the first comment already suggested, you just need to remove the `oldValue` parameter. The `initial` parameter is not supported in the old version, so you might need to add an `.onAppear` callback to do the same thing. If you needed `oldValue` in the closure then you could use a captured parameter, but it seems you're not, so you don't need to. Also, you need to be sure to use `newValue` in the closure and not the variable `isEnabled`, because in the old version of `.onChange` the closure sees the value before it has changed. But you're doing that already too.

Comment: @BenzyNeez even if I remove the oldValue param then I get the warning that the modifier has to be enclosed in a iOS 17 condition. This is because of the **initial: true** parameter in the onChange method. I think this is also only iOS 17.

Comment: @BenzyNeez thanks that helps! Would you know how to position a function somewhere in this code so that it executes when a view is popped off the stack via a swipe. I don't want the function to execute half way through the swipe.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower Did you try `.onDisappear`?

Comment: @BenzyNeez I already have tried onDisappear for my specific case I don't want to use that because it isn't guaranteed to execute and it executes too slow. I'd like to run something programmatically right after the pop action is called.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower If `.onDisappear` doesn't work then it sounds like you need to trigger it when some other change happens, perhaps using a delay. Suggest raising as a new post if necessary. If you can provide a minimal reproducible example then I'm sure you'll get some useful suggestions.

Comment: @BenzyNeez I made a new question for it specifically here if you have any ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77939564/swift-ui-execute-function-programmatically-when-view-disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution, hope it solves your query.

First, replace the `FullSwipeModifier` code with the following code for iOS 16 compatibility.

```
fileprivate struct FullSwipeModifier: ViewModifier {
        var isEnabled: Bool
        /// Gesture ID
        @Environment(\.popGestureID) private var gestureID
        
        func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
                .onAppear {
                    guard let gestureID = gestureID else { return }
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init(gestureID), object: nil, userInfo: [
                        "status": isEnabled
                    ])
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    guard let gestureID = gestureID else { return }
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init(gestureID), object: nil, userInfo: [
                        "status": false
                    ])
                }
        }
    }
```

You can use the `.onDisappear` modifier in your ContentView with a condition, it will be called when the view is fully swiped.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isEnabled: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        FullSwipeNavigationStack {
            NavigationLink("Leading Swipe View") {
                Text("hello")
                    .enableFullSwipePop(isEnabled)
                    .onDisappear {
                        // Check here, if the view is being dismissed due to a swipe
                        if !isEnabled {
                            // "View swiped away!"
                            print("View swiped away!")
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am already using .onDisappear to execute a function when the view is not longer presented. But there is a short delay between when the view is popped from the navigation stack and when the onDisappear actually executes. Is there someway I can programmatically execute a function right when the view is popped from the stack to avoid a delay?